# Impersonate a user to read contacts using a service account

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-people-api

Is it possible to impersonate a user to read their contacts?  I created a Service account, enabled Domain Wide Delegation and enabled the Admin and People API's.

I am able to successfully read the directory by impersonating my admin user.  However, I am unable to get a list of contacts for the user.  Instead I get a HTTP 404 error.

I appreciate any assistance.

Following is my code:

```
var google = require('googleapis').google;
var googleKey = require('./key/google-services.json');
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    googleKey.client_email,
    null, googleKey.private_key,
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'],
    '<redacted>.com' // ** the user that I am impersonating
);

jwtClient.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
        console.err(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Google auth success, access_token', tokens.access_token);

    //
    // 1.  accessing the directory works fine
    var directory = google.admin('directory_v1');
    directory.users.list({
        auth: jwtClient,

        customer: 'my_customer',
        orderBy: 'givenName',
        maxResults: 500,
        sortOrder: 'ASCENDING',
        viewType: 'domain_public', // admin_view
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(res.data.users);
    });

    //
    // listing contacts through the People API fails with a 404
    var people = google.people({version: 'v1'});
    people.people.connections.list({
        auth: jwtClient,
        resourceName: 'people/me',
        pageSize: 1000,
        sortOrder: 'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',
        personFields: 'names,emailAddresses,photos,addresses,phoneNumbers',
    }, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log(res.data.users);
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you added those scopes permissions into your security panel and is your service account user a admin on your domain? See this link please https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount

Comment: @Daniel_dev Yes to your question and I unfortunately have looked at the link you provided so much that I could regurgitate it :-).  Thank you for info; however.